# PHP Debugging issue - no logs, no errors

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, cakephp

I have a wee bit of a problem.

I got an application that handles tickets for our local custodians (using CakePHP as a framework) in case people need stuff fixed. This works wonderfully but after a recent database change the evaluation tool stopped working for any year that isn't <2015

I'm pretty sure this is a problem regarding my database or its entries, however I can't for the life of me figure out what the actual error is. All I get is "`An Internal Server Error has occurred.`"

`Display_errors` in my `php.ini` is on, so is `display_startup_errors` (both verified with `phpinfo()` to be `on`)

The servers' `error.log` for apache does not provide anything useful (last message logged was on the 3rd of this month) - neither does the database servers' mysql or apache error log.

I've essentially been sitting here wringing my hands going "HOW DO I DEBUG THIS!?"

Any help would be appreciated. Leave a comment if you need anything else.

Comment: Have you checked the CakePHP `error.log`? It should be in `$app/tmp/logs/error.log` (Where `$app` represents the name of your CakePHP application.)

Comment: in cakephp `app/config/core.php` check this line:- `Configure::write('debug', 2);` it will be 0 there initially so    make it 2 and then check your application, errors will now shown if any occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be caused by several reasons, the most common one is in your cake Framework, if you go to `app/Config/core.php` you will find this:

```
Configure::write('debug',0);
```

That number means the debug state, if you change it to 2 you will switch your application to development mode, so you will get errors and warnings.

Other thing I normally do for debug, if this doesn't solve your problem is to write:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will display all your errors.
I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Nice. This is perfect, I see all the errors I normally would, just what I was looking for. Now the fun can begin, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP you have to edit `app/Config/core.php`

`Configure::write('debug', 2);` enables the debug, while

`Configure::write('debug', 0);` disables it.

Comment: It's always better to write something to better explain, not just code.

Answer (score -1):

Put sample echo comment and exit in line by line , to test this type of errors. Because when getting internal errors the page cannot loaded. Check like the below code

echo "sample text";
exit;

Comment: I'm not sure it would help much.

Comment: we will find this error like this way only, if the page is not loaded

Comment: It wouldn't tell you what doesn't work, just change the behavior of the error.